# How is the increment operator evaluated in C programs?

Tags: c, operators

I have two expressions:

```
int a=5; 
int c=++a;// c=6, a=6
int b=a++;// b=6, a=7
```

In the second instruction, the increment is evaluated first and in the third instruction, the increment is evaluated after the assignment.

I know that the increment operator has a higher priority.  Can anyone explain to me why it's evaluated after assignment in the third expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is not related to the order of operations but to the definition of prefix `++` and postfix `++`.

The expression `++a` evaluates to the incremented value of `a`.  In contrast, the expression `a++` evaluates to the *current* value of `a`, and `a` is incremented as a side effect.

Section 6.5.2.4p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following about postfix `++`:

> The  result  of  the  postfix `++` operator  is  the  value  of  the 
>   operand.  As  a  side  effect,  the value of the operand object is
>   incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added  to
>   it).

And section 6.5.3.1p2 says the following about prefix `++`:

> The value of the operand of the prefix `++` operator is incremented.  The
>   result is the new value of the operand after incrementation.  The
>   expression `++E` is equivalent to `(E+=1)`

Answer (score 0):

`++a` and `a++` are simply different operators, despite the same symbol `++`. One is prefix-increment, one is postfix-increment. This has nothing to do with priority compared to assignment. (just like `a - b` and `-a` are different operators despite the same symbol `-`.)

**EDIT:** It was pointed out that this is about C and not C++... oops. So, the following explanation may be confusing if you only know C; all you need to know is that `int&` is a reference to an `int`, so it's like having a pointer but without the need to dereference it, so modifying `a` inside of these functions actually modifies the variable you passed into the functions.

You could imagine them like functions:

```cpp
int prefixIncrement(int& a) {
  return ++a;
}
```

...is the same as:

```cpp
int prefixIncrement(int& a) {
  a += 1;
  return a;
}
```

And:

```cpp
int postfixIncrement(int& a) {
  return a++;
}
```

...is the same as:

```cpp
int postfixIncrement(int& a) {
  int old = a;
  a += 1;
  return old;
}
```

*For nitpickers: Yes, actually we'd need move semantics on the return value for `postfixIncrement`.*

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT for your useful answer !

Comment: Right... added a warning about the `int&`